# Is it ok for a base class to contain a reference to one of its subclasses?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I wrote the following classes to create a tree-hiearchy, but since all node classes contain a parent node of type `ParentNode`, I would like to move that into the base class so I don't have to rewrite any code relating to the parent for all the node types. So, while it obviously *works*, Would it be considered bad practise to have a field of type `ParentNode` in the `NodeBase`-class, and if so, *What is the "correct" way of solving this problem?*

```
public abstract class NodeBase{
    /*Various general methods and properties*/
}
public class ParentNode : NodeBase{
    public readonly ParentNode Parent;
    public readonly List<NodeBase> Children;

    /*Methods etc related to parent nodes*/
}
public class LeafNode : NodeBase{
    public readonly ParentNode Parent;

    /*Methods etc related to leaf nodes*/
}
```

I can't just put a `public readonly NodeBase Parent` in the `NodeBase`-class, since `NodeBase` does not have the `Children`-list, and putting the `Children` there, would cause `LeafNode`s to also have that list.

Comment: Why do you need it there? You can solve the need of `Parent` via polymorphism. [Tell don't ask](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TellDontAsk) principle.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I don't *need* it there, I just want to move it there so I can write any code related to the parent in the base class instead of repeating it in every subclass.

Comment: You can add the methods in `NodeBase` as virtual and override it in `ParentNode` class and access the `Parent` and children there. [This video](https://youtu.be/4F72VULWFvc?t=7m53s) will be related I think.

Comment: @Closers: this is not "Opinion based" at all.

Comment: @HenkHolterman "Is it ok for a base class to contain a reference to one of its subclasses?" is opinion based. "What is the "correct" way of solving this problem?" is a perfectly valid question, but it wasn't there in initial question. Maybe added after the post got closed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If you don't mind expand a bit about what's wrong with marking such methods abstract or virtual?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, yes, I added it when I realized my original question seemed a bit vague.

Comment: The original question wasn't opinion based either. Questions about best practices, dependencies and architecture are quite common and OK here. Jave wasn't asking if it was 'pretty' or anything.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Asking for best practices are indeed opinion based. Just go and click ask new question button and type "<whatever> best practices" in question title. You'll get a tooltip/popup saying "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed".

Comment: "What is the best library/tool/..." is opinion based. Don't put too much trust in robo-guidance.

Comment: Well technically you should not do that simply because usually we want systems that are not coupled or rather, we try to reduce as much as possible the coupling. i dont personally think that its a good idea

Comment: @KevinAvignon - these 2 classes already have very strong coupling (static type relation). Adding a nav property does not change that very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern is used frequently and there is nothing wrong with it.

At first glance it might seem a little like a circular dependency but there is no real problem there. So when you need (want) a reference to a special type of derived node, you can and should model that exactly. Much better and safer than using a more general  `NodeBase Parent {get; set;}` and then to use that with typecasting and extra checks.

And it is quite common, for instance in the [XObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
class XObject
{
   public XElement Parent { get; }
   public XDocument Document { get; }
}

class XElement  : XObject { ... }   // with a few classes 
class XDocument : XObject { ... }   //    in between
```

Comment: Does this pattern have any name?

Comment: Not that I know of, it's just basic object modeling. A lot of tree-structured classes do this.

Comment: I neither agree nor disagree, but something about this answer seems lacking to me. "Some other schmo (granted, a big schmo) did it, you can do it." Microsoft has, on occasion, produced some ill-advised patterns, so I would not necessarily take their example as license to replicate it.

Answer (score 3):

While I wouldn't consider it bad practice it would indicate to me that I've designed something wrong.

In general it doesn't make any sense to keep a reference of a sub class in a super class.

In this case I don't see why you need to have a separate class for leaf nodes and parent nodes. All nodes can have children and a parent. Being a leaf node is just a result of having no children, any methods that only affect leaf node could just check the count of the list to confirm no children exist. Just like any RootNode checks would look at the parent node.

Comment: "It would indicate to me that I've designed something wrong." Yes, that is exactly the feeling I get, but I don't really know how to design it to solve the problem. The reason I want a separate class for leaf nodes is to reduce complexity further down the chain. When I started out I had a single type of node, but the method became extremely cluttred with allt he calls to `IsRoot`, `IsLeaf`, etc.

Comment: No, it isn't wrong or uncommon. See for example `XObject.Parent`, of type `XElement: XObject`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thanks for the example. Since this question got closed, I'm going to go ahead and a `ParentNode` in the `BaseNode` for now. If it opens again, feel free to post a more detailed example/explanation as an answer.